# JQuery hide table columns with rowspan

Tags: jquery, html-table, hide

I want to hide a table column, but using jQuery `.hide()` or `.toggle()` on columns with rowspan attribute seems to "pass" that attribute to the previous row and mess up the table.

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('#tbl td:last-child').toggle();
});
```

Look at the simple example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/SEwVP/

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exact logical criteria ? A column index ? Don't your column handle different data ?

Comment: try with visibiltity attribute css

Comment: your jquery is behaving as it should, but since you have different number of tds in the rows that's why when you hide the last child you will see different number of cells in each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the @dystroy for his input.

Based on his answer, here's the simple solution:

```
var lastChilds = $('#tbl td:last-child');
lastChilds.each(function(i){
    var rowSpan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    if(rowSpan !== undefined){
      lastChilds.splice(i+1, rowSpan-1);
    }
    $(this).hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The last `td` might be of a different column, so that's normal.

In this case where only the last column hold rowspans, you could use the child index :

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('#tbl td:nth-child(5)').toggle();
});
```

If you want a solution valid if you have rowspan in any column, then you'll probably have to precompute for each cell its real column index. It's doable but more it would probably be more rational to use simpler solutions, like having a class depending on the data. It thus would depend on the semantic and production process of your table.

Comment: *"The last td might be of a different column, so that's normal."* Of course, it had to be something simple and reasonable!

Comment: Doesn't work with rowspan rows